# Google Apps Script is taking too much time, is there a way to reduce the runtime?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

```
function dataManp() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var copySheet = ss.getSheetByName("My-Sheet-1");
  var pasteSheet = ss.getSheetByName("My-Sheet-2");
  var clearContentRange = pasteSheet.getRange("A1:Z100");
  clearContentRange.clearContent();

  var source = copySheet.getRange("a1:f100");

  var destination = pasteSheet.getRange("a1:f100");

  source.copyTo(destination, {formatOnly:true , contentsOnly:true});
  source.copyTo(destination,SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_COLUMN_WIDTHS,false);

  var rows = pasteSheet.getDataRange();
  var numRows = rows.getNumRows();
  var values = rows.getValues();

  var rowsDeleted = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i <= numRows - 1; i++) {
    var row = values[i];
    if (row[3] == '') {
      var deleteRowNum = (parseInt(i)+1) - rowsDeleted
      pasteSheet.deleteRow(deleteRowNum);
     // temp_array[i] = i
      rowsDeleted++;
    }
  }
  pasteSheet.deleteColumn(2)
}
```

Hi,

I have written the following script to perform the following operations,

1. Copy data from `My-Sheet-1` and paste to `My-Sheet-2`
2. Deletion of rows that corresponds to empty cells in column 3.
3. After that deletion of column 2

Rigthnow, the `My-Sheet-1` contains only 60 rows and 20, the script is taking approximately 7 secs to complete. However in future the number of rows may extend to some 1000. *Is there a way to optimize the above code, so that it takes less time to complete*.

My observation is that, copy and pasting the data takes just milli secs. The major time consuming part are the operations, I am performing in the `pasteSheet` after pasting it. It may be helpful, if we can copy `My-Sheet-1` to a temporary variable (copy everything including the formulas, format specifications, values, text etc..) and perform all operations in the temporary variable and then paste everything in the temporary variable to the desired target sheet. But, I don't know, how to copy everything in a sheet to a temporary variable, also, I am not sure, whether this will reduce the time or not. *I would be glad, if I can get some help on this as well (i.e. copying everything in a sheet to a temporary variable, perfrom operations on the variables and then paste data in the variable to a new sheet)*

Thank you

**Edit - 1**

Would like to add that, `My-Sheet-1` contains mixed data (i.e. numerics, color formatted text, formulas in some cells etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Explanation:

`deleteRow()` takes some time per execution, so it's not recommended to use on hundreds of rows in a loop.

**Simple answer would be:**

1. Make a 2D array for Sheet1 using `getValues()`.
2. Delete / filter out array elements depending if row[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kesD2.png) is blank.
3. Use `setValues()` to write the filtered array into Sheet2.

**Sample Code:**

```
function dataManp() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var copySheet = ss.getSheetByName("My-Sheet-1");
  var pasteSheet = ss.getSheetByName("My-Sheet-2");
  var lr = copySheet.getLastRow();
  var clearContentRange = pasteSheet.getRange(1,1,lr,26);
  clearContentRange.clearContent();

  var source = copySheet.getRange(1,1,lr,6);
  var destination = pasteSheet.getRange(1,1,lr,6);

  source.copyTo(destination, {formatOnly:true , contentsOnly:true});
  source.copyTo(destination,SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_COLUMN_WIDTHS,false);
  destination.clearContent();

  var values = source.getValues();

  var temp_array = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < lr; i++) {
    var rowValue = values[i];
    if (rowValue[2] != '') {
      temp_array.push(rowValue);
    }
  }

  var newDest = pasteSheet.getRange(1,1,temp_array.length,6)
  newDest.setValues(temp_array);
  pasteSheet.deleteColumn(2);
}
```

One caveat is that you need to have the same format for all rows in a column.

**Sample Input:**

[image]

**Sample Output:**

[image]

Comment: thank you very much, a sample code would be very much helpful.

Comment: Are there specific columns in which formulas are placed? If you need to copy the formulas to sheet 2 you would need to use getFormulas() and setFormulas(), which needs a specific range.

Comment: Yes, @carlos-m  I have some formulas in some columns (for example on column 2), but for now, I don't need to copy the formulas, just copying the values and corresponding text and cell formatting will be enough. Since, I don't know, how to copy text alone with cell and text formatting, I am deleting that column at the end of the above code.

Comment: No problem, one caveat though is that the format of all rows in a column should be the same